# Nexus Management VRF on same VLAN as LAN switches

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-nexus, vrf

1

Hi All.

I searched this question but I'm not finding anything relevant, or I'm not understanding the results properly. I have all my L2 switches remote management access, SSH/SFTP, configured on a specific vlan 12, with subnet 10.0.12.0/24. Route goes through a Barracuda NGFW with firewall rules restricting traffic to/from vlan 12.

I picked up a Nexus 3064 I'm looking to use as a core router for my vlans. My question is, how do I specify the management vrf to use vlan 12 for management so it's on the same subnet as the rest of the LAN switches?

Do I specify the ip on int mgmt0 like 10.0.12.253, then specify the SVI vlan12 with an ip as the to be the subnet gateway like 10.0.12.254?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: SSH/TFTP that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using in-band management (vlan 12), then you don’t need a separate VRF. You can simply use the SVI for vlan 12. Be sure to apply the appropriate ACL to the management interface.

Mgmt0 is a physical interface for out of band management.

Alternatively you can connect the mgmt0 interface to an access port on vlan 12.  The FW is your default gateway for the VRF.

Comment: Oh great. So I don't really need to worry about the specific Management vrf and just make the SVI like the others under default vrf with acl for in-band? That's simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: If the answer helps you, consider marking it as accepted.